# It looks like the std::move_iterator only works with string data types

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, stdvector, move-semantics

It is possible to move data from source container to destination container using the `std::move_iterator` if the container has string types of data. `std::move_iterator` does not operate with other data types in the container.

**std::move_iterator works fine**

```cpp
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::move_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

using namespace std;
int main () {
    
    vector<string>src = {"one", "two", "three", "four"}, des(4);
    using Iter = vector<string>::iterator;
    
    //move the data from src to des
    move_iterator<Iter>beginitr(src.begin());
    move_iterator<Iter>enditr(src.end());
    Iter diter = des.begin();
    
    while(beginitr != enditr)
    {
        *diter++ = *beginitr++;
    }
    
    cout << "src container size: " << src.size() << endl;
    cout << "data: " ;
    for_each(begin(src),end(src), [](string x){cout << x ;});
    cout << endl << "THE END";

  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
src container size: 4
data: 
THE END
```

**std::move_iterator dose not move the data**

```cpp
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::move_iterator
#include <list>       // std::vector
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

using namespace std;
int main () {
    
    list<int>src = {1,2,3,4}, des(4);
    using Iter = list<int>::iterator;
    
    //move the data from src to des
    move_iterator<Iter>beginitr = make_move_iterator(src.begin());
    move_iterator<Iter>enditr = make_move_iterator(src.end());
    Iter diter = des.begin();
    
    while(beginitr != enditr)
    {
        *diter++ = *beginitr++;
    }
    
    cout << "src container size: " << src.size() << endl;
    for_each(begin(src),end(src), [](int x){cout << x << endl;});
    

  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
src container size: 4
1
2
3
4
```

It appears that integer data gets copied to the target container rather than being moved.

Comment: Copying an integer is same as copying it. You can reproduce this with a single `std::move`, without iterators. Moving is supposed to be a faster alternative to copying that leaves the original in an unspecified state, and zeroing moved-from integer is slower than not.

Comment: Unlike `std::string` moving primitive types does a copy, which is cheap for them. Also, not that `std::move` or `std::move_iter` doesn't move anything, rather cast to a rvalue type. Move happens automatically, if applicable. For instance, the `std::move(src)`  would have worked in both cases.

Comment: A side note: regarding [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: std::move_iterator works with both string and int types.  It appears there is a misunderstanding what **move** does:  it moves the **resources** from one object to another object, it copies the rest.  The original object is "gutted"; a hollowed out husk suitable for destruction or reassignment (for most standard library types; your own types can have different post-move guarantees).  (The `move` "cast" just allows an lvalue to be treated as an rvalue for purposes of construction or assignment.)  A `string` has resources; an `int` does not.

Comment: Moved-from standard types will be in "a valid but unspecified state". "Unchanged" is a totally valid state, so conforming.

Comment: Thank to all for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference using a move iterator makes is that dereferencing the iterator yields an rvalue reference. If only the copy assignment operator is available, but no move assignment operator, this will be used as "fallback".

The following code demonstrates this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

struct Test
{
#if 0
    Test(Test&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test::Test(Test&&)\n";
    }

    Test& operator=(Test&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test& Test::operator=(Test&&)\n";
        return *this;
    }
#endif 
    
    Test(Test const&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test::Test(Test const&)\n";
    }

    Test& operator=(Test const&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test::Test()\n";
    }

};

 
int main() {
    std::list<Test> src(4);
    std::list<Test> des(4);

    std::cout << "-------------------copy with move iterator--------------------\n";
    std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(src.end()), des.begin());

    std::cout << "-------------------copy with normal iterator--------------------\n";
    std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), des.begin());
}
```

Output with `#if 0` left as is:

```
...
-------------------copy with move iterator--------------------
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
-------------------copy with normal iterator--------------------
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
```

Output with move semantics defined (`#if 1` instead of `#if 0`):

```
...
-------------------copy with move iterator--------------------
Test& Test::operator=(Test&&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test&&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test&&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test&&)
-------------------copy with normal iterator--------------------
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
```

[Godbolt Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BgVU1AnUNBMWRMXGJtvWNzbltwz1hfWUDCQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1CYbbmLAJIQILIfYJhoAgpvbu5gHR04KBMSYrFc392ZbDB2Xn2hzchDiTCIxB%2BdwegKeLzctDw7xhfwBQJBRy8jmRBAAnmjfu9iF4HHsACqYVGwgDsVlh/zwVD2Gl%2Bew5lOpBAgVNRZn85n8c3ZnJM9NFnM573QIBQSwIiNBBzMZj5BDl6t53KFQpFAFY3AxzGZDgzblLxQARX6Srn8/x7VDJCFQw5W7UOvV28XmqVSmVytA4pVHFVqnUC%2B0akDO10kd2egi6gUGo0ms12qWfAjLBh7ABUBAQKMzd0ttJtjI2rmZB3LYobHK16r2aAYDpFTYOEu7AYIsvlIdBypN6s13KTbYEnZMhuNqrLFrFldt3fVQqdLuIkITGw9rfbs%2B7vqz0oHQYVobc4Y3UfHse3u%2Bh%2B6nR%2BTqbn6cXGz9/o5OZ5oWxalr%2BPqrrC66Tl2y4cqefbnoOwaKiOYZjtyE7vBAaYLqaYEnhB9x0ja%2BFERavxhIqLBMGE2E9n%2BHKBiAyKokcG4bNgewKCsECSCKpH9oOLHJmxOocXsWAKLx/HmnaTHIde4YALQqapanqWpaDJPiewAO7nHsLCoAAbs84I7lCGlWVZX64UugmXtpEBMdRADWmAAPpGaZHnmc%2BzkrAAdLEwC0XMCxcReIBuZ53meX5UIBcggWuNhEWScFmChQwaVLnJUUKahN4mtZpUqVpOn6cWewMCQ1G0HsCUkGVZW2RmAmIY5%2BJJZl2XYaQXFBal6XUr1YUybalYcAstCcPqvB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1hcUsKzPJsPCkBqS3TQsrkgPqGj6JwkgLZovCrRwvAKCAF2HVoCxwLASCYKo1Q4iQ5CUA0wAKMohiYLQQgIKgumLftaAsMkdCQpkoPhBDUMw7dpDw4j9DxMAXAbFw2OoAjdBxBErBrLwOPk8QADyOKQ9Di3Ld91S3MQwOcLw7PIHU%2BCLbw/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqEdpC6MTBhGCgG2WPoeDRE9kALM6jgzjzizLKsegymEqPg8zmPcLwuk7sknA8DNc03fL93YD9yB/cQeyqAAHP4Sn%2BJIezAMgyB7ITgVcHsEDrZY1gDbghAkCqRNzLwr3HaQp3nZdHDXaQrN3YbT0vbd4X52YrvLfdmcVwspnEOkziSEAA)

For arithmetic types like `int` there are only copy semantics, not move semantics leaving the source list unmodified in your code.